# How do I display the name from another model in my view, by the ID in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So i have created 2 models 'Team' & 'Match', 1 controller 'MatchController' and a view 'matches/index.blade.php'.

The Team model has an ID & name.
The Match model has an ID, homeTeam_id & awayTeam_id.
The MatchController has an index method.
The view shows all the matches in de database correctly, but with the homeTeam_id, what I would like is show the name for the teams, from the Team model.

How do i do that? This is what i have now in my view:

```
@foreach ($matches as $key => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->homeTeam_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->awayTeam_id }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two relationships between `Team` and `Match` models:

```
public function homeTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'homeTeam_id', 'id');
}

public function awayTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'awayTeam_id', 'id');
}
```

And then load the data:

```
$matches = Match::with('homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->get();
```

To display team name do this:

```
{{ $value->homeTeam->name }}
```

Comment: Thanks, it also works without `$matches = Match::with('homeTeam', 'awayTeam')->get();`.
my controller is: `public function index()
    {
        //get all the matches
        $matches = Match::all();
        
        // load the view and pass the matches
        return view('matches.index')
            ->with ('matches', $matches);
    }`

Comment: @Mwisho if you'll not use `with()`, your code will create multiple queries. You can read about this problem [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)